# Rollback the changes made by a procedure

Tags: oracle

I have a procedure `myProcedure`

```
create or replace
procedure myProcedure as 
begin
--some checking goes here
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES..
--some checking goes here
   DELETE FROM table2;
end myProcedure;
```

I have called this procedure and it executed without any errors. 
Can I `Rollback` the changes made by this procedure?

Comment: if there hasn't been implicit or explicit `commit` then yes, you can `ROLLBACK` any changes made by the stored procedure.

Comment: I did `Rollback` from my plsql window. Soon after the procedure executed. But `table2` is not restored.

Comment: You have to `rollback` in the same session you executed your stored procedure. If you executed your stored procedure, then closed the window(not sure what PL/SQL window you are referring to.), it's very likely that you've triggered an implicit commit(depending on a client). If so, the `rollback` won't help you. As one of the simplest methods to restore your data you can, depending on the undo retention value, use flashback queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You're looking for SAVEPOINT. Savepoints save transactions states and help rollback to specified point in time.

```
create or replace
procedure myProcedure as 
begin
--some checking goes here
  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES..
  SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
--some checking goes here
  DELETE FROM table2;
exception
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      ROLLBACK TO do_insert;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insert has been rolled back');
end myProcedure;
```

Check Oracle documentation:

[Example 6-38, "Using SAVEPOINT With ROLLBACK"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG)

[Example 6-39, "Reusing a SAVEPOINT With ROLLBACK"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#CJABIBIC)